# Ansible playbook does not change files, but returns success

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to disable selinux on 25 servers.

```
- name: disable selinux
  selinux: state=disabled
```

Serwers are defined in host file and I am running the playbook with

```
ansible-playbook -v -i hosts ansible/server-prepare.yml
```

The output looks like this:

```
GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [10.0.0.10]
(... other servers ...)

TASK: [prepare | disable selinux] *********************************************
changed: [10.0.0.10] => {"changed": true, "configfile": "/etc/selinux/config", "msg": "state change will take effect next reboot", "policy": "targeted", "state": "disabled"}
(... other servers ...)
```

However, the value in config file on host 10.0.0.10 is not changed:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
```

I am aware, that I need to reboot after the config file is changed, but the config file is not changed at all.
For all commands in playbook ansible returns success, however there is no effect.

For now, I only tried adding `-v` to `ansible-playbook` command. Do I have some other options to debug this? I am using `ansible-playbook 1.9.2`.

Answer (score 1):

For testing I added:

```
connection: local
```

This caused the changes to be made to the localhost, even though ansible reported running on other ips.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this problem is solved, but still it's worth answering for future reference.

Similar situation happens when `control_path` variable is set in `~/.ansible.cfg` to a invalid, non-unique value, eg.

```
control_path=%(directory)s/%%r
```

Ansible then gets first successful response from any host and prints it as a result for every other host, providing false positives. I guess this is due to the fact, that ansible sockets aren't unique any more.

If you need to change `control path` to a shorter path due to length limit, use:

```
control_path=%(directory)s/%%C
```

`%%C` is a hash of `%%h-%%p-%%r`